# how to transform and truncate time stamps from starting time using lubridate?

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate

I want to transforming the time stamps of a dataset into something more workable, and am new to lubridate/R.

The data originally came in `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M` and would like the change this to `%d %H` from the starting time.

I want to truncate the data down to DMY_H then rearrange it to Hours and Days after origin

Here is sample of the data:

```
time    dht22_t dht11_t dht22_h dht11_h db  pa  treatment_hive  wifi
01/09/2014 15:19    NA      NA  NA      NA  51.75467    NA      0   1
01/09/2014 15:20    30.8    31  59.8    44  55.27682    100672  0   1
01/09/2014 15:21    30.8    31  60.3    44  54.81995    100675  0   1
01/09/2014 15:22    30.8    31  60.9    44  54.14134    100671  0   1
01/09/2014 15:23    30.8    31  61.1    44  53.88574    100672  0   1
01/09/2014 15:24    30.8    31  61.2    44  53.68800    100680  0   1
```

Thanks!
EDIT:

The code:

```
df$time<-format(ymd_hms(df$time), '%d %H:%M:%S')
```

changed the days, but not the hours minutes seconds to a starting time or origin.
Ideally, it would look like this:

```
    time DHT22_t DHT11_t DHT22_h DHT11_h       db      pa hive_id treatment_hive wifi
01 15:00:00      NA      NA      NA      NA 51.75467      NA       1              0    1
01 16:00:00    30.8      31    59.8      44 55.27682 100.672       1              0    1
01 17:00:00    30.8      31    60.3      44 54.81995 100.675       1              0    1
```

EDIT:

```
> dput(droplevels(head(Hive2)))
structure(list(time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2014-09-01 15:25:05", 
"2014-09-01 15:25:09", "2014-09-01 15:25:11", "2014-09-01 15:25:15", 
"2014-09-01 15:25:18", "2014-09-01 15:25:20"), class = "factor"), 
    DHT22_t = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), DHT11_t = c(0L, 31L, 31L, 
    31L, 31L, 31L), DHT22_h = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), DHT11_h = c(0L, 
    51L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 50L), db = c(60.8, 59.4, 60.4, 59.2, 
    60.3, 60.2), kPa = c(NA, 100.798, 100.792, 100.791, 100.79, 
    100.791), hive_id = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), treatment_hive = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), wifi = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("time", 
"DHT22_t", "DHT11_t", "DHT22_h", "DHT11_h", "db", "kPa", "hive_id", 
"treatment_hive", "wifi"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

for this code:

```
dt1 <- ymd_hms(Hive2$time)
v1 <- times(format(dt1, '%H:%M:%S'))
dt2<- paste(format(dt1, '%d'), v1-v1[1])
> dput(head(dt2))
c("01  0.000000e+00", "01  4.629630e-05", "01  6.944444e-05", 
"01  1.157407e-04", "01  1.504630e-04", "01  1.736111e-04")
```

and this:

```
dt2.1<- paste(format(dt1, '%d %H:%M:%S'), v1-v1[1])
> dput(head(dt2.1))
c("01 15:25:05  0.000000e+00", "01 15:25:09  4.629630e-05", "01 15:25:11 6.944444e-05", 
 "01 15:25:15  1.157407e-04", "01 15:25:18  1.504630e-04", "01 15:25:20  1.736111e-04"
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(chron)
 dt1 <- dmy_hm(df$time)
```

NOTE: Based on the example provided, the times are `15:19:00`, `15:20:00`.  One reason to show dataset using `dput`.

```
  dt1
 #[1] "2014-09-01 15:19:00 UTC" "2014-09-01 15:20:00 UTC"
 #[3] "2014-09-01 15:21:00 UTC" "2014-09-01 15:22:00 UTC"
 #[5] "2014-09-01 15:23:00 UTC" "2014-09-01 15:24:00 UTC"

 v1 <- times(format(dt1, '%H:%M:%S')) 
 paste(format(dt1, '%d'), v1-v1[1])
 #[1] "01 00:00:00" "01 00:01:00" "01 00:02:00" "01 00:03:00" "01 00:04:00"
 #[6] "01 00:05:00"
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset "Hive2"

```
dt1 <- ymd_hms(Hive2$time)
v1 <- times(format(dt1, '%H:%M:%S'))
v1
#[1] 15:25:05 15:25:09 15:25:11 15:25:15 15:25:18 15:25:20
paste(format(dt1, '%d'), v1-v1[1])
#[1] "01 00:00:00" "01 00:00:04" "01 00:00:06" "01 00:00:10" "01 00:00:13"
#[6] "01 00:00:15"
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(time = c("01/09/2014 15:19", "01/09/2014 15:20", 
 "01/09/2014 15:21", "01/09/2014 15:22", "01/09/2014 15:23", "01/09/2014 15:24"
 ), dht22_t = c(NA, 30.8, 30.8, 30.8, 30.8, 30.8), dht11_t = c(NA, 
 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), dht22_h = c(NA, 59.8, 60.3, 60.9, 61.1, 
 61.2), dht11_h = c(NA, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L), db = c(51.75467, 
 55.27682, 54.81995, 54.14134, 53.88574, 53.688), pa = c(NA, 100672L, 
 100675L, 100671L, 100672L, 100680L), treatment_hive = c(0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), wifi = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("time", 
 "dht22_t", "dht11_t", "dht22_h", "dht11_h", "db", "pa", "treatment_hive", 
 "wifi"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This converted the days, but the hours minutes seconds are still the same as the original data, not time after the start of the experiment.

Comment: For example, it looks like this: 01 15:19:04, 01 15:19:08, 01 15:19:11    01, instead of like this: 01 00:00:00, 01 00:00:04, 01: 00:00: 07, etc etc.

Comment: i could not get the same output. first i had to add the seconds onto the 1st line of code: "dt1 <- ymd_hms(Hive1$time)" to get it to work and then everything followed but the output looked like this: [2041] "01  7.405093e-02" "01  7.408565e-02" "01  7.412037e-02" "01  7.415509e-02"...maybe from here I can convert it back into d hms?

Comment: @Evan I guess you need to change the options ie. `op <-  options(scipen= 100, digits=2)` and try again.  Having said that, the output of `dt1` is POSIXct class, and `v1` is times class.  So, it is not clear which step converts this to scientific form.

Comment: @Evan BTW, it should be `dmy_hm(df$time)` instead of `ymd_hms` based on the format of your dataset.  You can check by using both, there will be change in dates.

Comment: w/r/t the last comment, i changed the code to ymd_hms because otherwise this format popped up: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
>

Comment: @Evan Is it on the same `dput` output as showed in my post?  I used `lubridate_1.3.3`

Comment: And this message popped after I used as.numeric, as.matrix, and as.POSTIXct to convert the original data

Comment: @Evan If you look at the `str(data)`, it is character and I didn't change it to `POSIXct`

Comment: I am using the same lubridate_1.3.3. Hmm I am confused why my original format is not working nor are the other types i tried.

Comment: what does "on the same dput output as showed" mean?

Comment: I think i need to use ymd_hms and then the (truncate, .. ) argument in lubridate to remove the seconds

Comment: @Evan It means if you copy the `df` from my post.

Comment: oh right ok. Ya it worked perfectly with your df, but when i tried my data, it did not work and i had to include the seconds..

Comment: @Evan It is better if you showed the `dput` output in your post for reproducibility. ie. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69322/discussion-between-evan-and-akrun).

Comment: @Evan I don't find any problem in the updated dataset except that it is `ymd_hms` rather than `dmy_hms`.